# ConTeXt: How to have line numbering in a two column layout for one column only?

Tags: context, columns, line-numbering

I am trying to recreate a layout for some dictionary with ConTeXt. It is a two column layout with line numbering between the columns, that is, there is only one numbering for both columns. How can I do this with ConTeXt?

I would need either an option to activate line numbering only for one column, which, as far as I can see, does not exist; or I could use the "command" option for "\setuplinenumbering" to make the line numbers dissappear for one column, but then I would need some way to decide whether a line number belongs to the first or to the second column, some command that returns to me the number of the actual column, which I can't find, too.

For illustration, I will give a minimal example of what I did and did not achieve yet:

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setupbodyfont[9pt]

\setupcolumns[
    n=2,
    distance=1cm,
]

\setuplinenumbering[
    step=5,
    method=page,
    location=right,
    align=flushright,
    width=.25cm
]

\starttext

\startcolumns
\startlinenumbering
\dorecurse{10}{\input lorem}\par
\stoplinenumbering
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

Which results in the following result:

[image: Two columns, both numbered]

I need only the line numbers between the columns. How can I make the numbers to the right disappear?

Comment: For those who might be interested: I now found a solution, which works, but which I don't consider a good solution: Hiding the numbers to the right by a layer with a white strip:  
`\definelayer[mask]
    [
        state=repeat,
        x=0mm,
        y=0mm,
        width=\paperwidth,
        height=\paperheight,
    ]

\setlayer[mask][hoffset=\textwidth]{\blackrule[
    height=\textheight,
    width=3cm,
    color=white]}

\setupbackgrounds[text][background={foreground,mask}]
`  
Works for my purpose, but I would still be interested in a better solution.